# unable to access repositories through sudo apt-get update

Tags: connection, apt-get, linux-mint

part of output of "sudo apt-get update" command:

```
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease
Ign http://packages.linuxmint.com rafaela InRelease
Ign http://extra.linuxmint.com rafaela InRelease
Err http://archive.canonical.com trusty Release.gpg
 Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.191 80]
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease
Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release.gpg
 Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Ign http://archive.canonical.com trusty Release
Err http://packages.linuxmint.com rafaela Release.gpg
 Connection failed [IP: 68.235.39.11 80]
Err http://extra.linuxmint.com rafaela Release.gpg
 Connection failed [IP: 68.235.39.11 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg
 Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.153 80]
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release
Ign http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://packages.linuxmint.com rafaela Release
Ign http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner i386 Packages/DiffIndex
```

i am getting a lot of "Connection Failed " errors,
i have tried every solution like changing nameserver, removing unwanted repository links from apt.sources file and read every stackoverflow link still can't resolve it.

i also have to mention that i am using internet on my university library which has firewall but the IP addresses where the "Connection failed" happens is accessible through browser without any hassle.

is there any work around for this situation?.

Comment: do you also get: W: GPG error: http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY *   ? If so, try to add the proper GPG keys

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using a Debian 8.1 (Jessie) virtual machine with Vagrant and VirtualBox...

I have been experiencing similar issues for the last day or so. I just installed a 'brand new' internet security suite (Bullguard Premium Protection) and found out their firewall seems to be blocking connections, and conflicting with my Windows firewall. I'm still tweaking firewall rules in Bullguard, but at least found out what was causing the issue.

In your case specifically, I recommend looking at any firewalls you have (with your internet security suite and/or operating system) and seeing if connections are being blocked. If you are using a VPN, or some sort of I.P blocking software (e.g. PeerBlock), you might want to look at those too.

I hope this helps somehow - it might not be entirely specific to your problem, but thought it might give you some pointers.